# What to do after soft reset to my last commit ? Commit or pull first? or Pull then commit, or...?

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull, git-reset

I needed to discard a file of my last commit, so I soft reset it and now I can commit again but GitHub Desktop gives me the Pull origin option and I am wondering what to do:

- Commit and then push or vice versa?
- Or pull force or something?

I make soft reset of my last commit and discard a file so now I have a pull origin option in the Git Hub desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What a soft reset is

A soft reset undoes the most recent commit but leaves both your working tree and the index in a state that still reflects that undone commit. Thus:

- If you were to commit *right after the soft reset* without changing anything else, you would get a commit that looks exactly like the commit you just undid (except maybe for the message, and of course the time).
- If, on the other hand, you make a change in the working tree and add that change to the index and *then* commit, you have replaced the undone commit with a new and different commit.

(Note that you could have accomplished exactly the same thing with `commit --amend`.)

#### Afterwards

So then what?

- If you had already pushed the "last commit" before you reset and made a new commit, you now have *changed history*. Therefore, if the purpose is (say) to make sure that this new commit lacks the "naughty" file on both your local and remotely, you must *push with force* in order to get the new commit to upload to the remote.
- On the other hand, if you have *not* pushed the "last commit" before the reset, then there is nothing particular to do; after doing a new add-and-commit you can just push directly to the remote if that's your goal, or you can just keep working (edit-add-commit).

Comment: Ok so I after the soft reset I left my changes uncommitted ,because I was wondering what to do. And in the git Status it tells me that my branch is 5 commits behind the origin and can be fast forwarded. What is the steps in this case?

Comment: The way I read it, my answer answers that.